# AVD Not working correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've read the comment of [Prashanth Sams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482709/prashanth-sams) in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow).
What's bothering me is that when i run my new AVD, it doesn't work now and it's all black. It was working way back when im still using ARM based AVDs. I'm using Eclipse IDe btw, and have all updated updates.